# Can't find the CORE WAMP download, keeps giving me addons only

Tags: wamp

I'm going through the official WAMP website too. It direct me to SourceForce which seems right. I then click Download and it start trying to give me wampserver3_x64_addon_mariadb10.3.7.exe. What happened with Wamp and SourceForge and is there any way to download WAMP right now?

Comment: If anybody runs into this issue for now, instead of clicking on the green "Download" button, just go to the "Files" tab. Then click on the folder "WampServer 3", then "WampServer 3.0.0". Finally click on the actual file "wampserver3.1.3_x64.exe" for the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that the WAMPServer Backup Repo is a lot easier to navigate.

It is maintained by the same guy that builds the releases that are placed into SourceForge and is completely legitimate. It is often a few days ahead of SourceForge as they take time to do their own checks on the release.

You can [find it here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

Also remember you must install a Full Release first, then you can apply any of the ADDON versions of Apache / PHP / MySQL / mariaDB that you need to match the development environment you require.